# what's unclear about question 13381?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A question entitled "https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13381/how-can-a-prophet-say-his-prayers-behind-imam-mahdi-may-allah-hasten-his-appear" is heavily voted and has got an answer. But. it is labeled as unclear! I'd like to know the vague points in this post for clarification.

- **Update:** The question is now closed !

Answer (score 2):

The question looks very unclear since all you do is mention that Jesus will pray behind Mahdi but then ask how Jesus can pray behind Mahdi.  It is barely even a question.

It is unclear why you are asking this question or what your problem is because you already know that the prophet will pray behind the mahdi but you don't explain at all why the idea of a prophet praying behind mahdi is a big deal.

It is unclear what you are expecting in an answer because you ask how a prophet can pray behind a non-prophet but you don't explain what you mean.  Are you asking because you assume that prophets don't pray or they can't pray behind people or that non-prophet's can't lead prayers or even just that the mahdi isn't allowed to lead a prayer or do you just want to know how the physical prayer is performed even though there's no suggestion in the question that prophets or mahdi pray differently from anyone else at all?

It is unclear who you are asking because your question mentions Sahih Muslim which is a Sunni book but you tag it shiism which suggests you want a Shi'i answer but then you tell the only answer that he is "easily looking from the shia prospective" which doesn't indicate whether you want a shia perspective or not or whether you're complaining about the answer or not and it doesn't even seem to be a constructive comment so what's the point?

It is unclear what the comments under your question have to do with the question since you're arguing about whether hadiths talk about mahdi or not but your question doesn't look to be about that at all.  Which makes the whole point of quoting the hadith in your question unclear since it has nothing to do with what you're asking because you already know that.

It is unclear whether the answer even answers your question because it explains the requirements for someone to lead a prayer which seems to be what you're asking even though you already know that the mahdi will lead the prayer and it even got voted which means a bunch of other people also thought it answered the question but you didn't accept it.  If you didn't accept it it suggests you don't want that answer but you didn't mention anywhere that you don't want that answer or what you want in an answer that that answer doesn't already give you which just means that other people who want to answer the question don't know what you want.

Comment: From Sunni perspective, Prophets are divine characters. So if they are divine characters (and Imams are not), Jesus shouldn't let others lead the prayer under normal situation. Now, what makes him follow others lead in prayer?